# OpenCV VideoCapture initialization with an RTMP url is taking more than 30 seconds

Tags: opencv, nginx, gstreamer, rtmp, obs

I'm doing the following to open an RTMP stream using opencv

`VideoCapture cap;`

`cap.open("rtmp://192.168.1.122/live/secret-key0");`

Then the program waits for 30 seconds for the connection and then resumes and the video is captures. I want to capture the video instantly the moment the program starts. I there something that I'm missing?

When I try to capture the stream from OBS over RTMP I have no delay in opening the stream using VideoCapture.

Here my VideoWriter statement

`VideoWriter out("appsrc ! videoconvert ! queue  ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=480 ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=60/1 ! x264enc bitrate=1000 noise-reduction=10000 pass=cbr speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency ! flvmux name=mux ! rtmpsink location=rtmp://192.168.1.122/live/secret-key0", CAP_GSTREAMER,CV_FOURCC('X','2','6','4'),30,Size(640,480),true);`

The RTMP stream that I'm trying to play is from nginx-rtmp server.

Comment: Which environment and machine you are running it?

Comment: I'm running the nginx-rtmp on a Google Compute Engine VM and running the OpenCv application on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine

Comment: Hey @pruthvidr did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @Greg0ry I couldn't fix it back then. I think it has something to do with the keyframe interval. I tried to fine tune the stream by changing the value of the keyframe interval but I didn't gind any success.